# Projectile motion explanation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

I’m studying projectiles at the moment and I am sure this is a very simple question, but can someone explain if I have a light object (a tennis ball) and a heavier object (a similar size solid steel ball) and launch them at the same initial velocity and the same angle, will the range be the same? Any why? (Neglecting air resistance etc)

Comment: In vacuum ,  $$R=\frac{v^{2}\sin2A}{g} $$...So no dependence on mass is observed...

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: What forces are acting on each ball after launch? What's the acceleration of each ball after launch? Think carefully about it and you'll answer your own question.

Comment: The only force acting on the ball after launch is gravity.

Comment: https://www.physicskey.com/11/what-is-projectile-motion

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't yet learnt about forces. Need not worry!

In projectile kinematics the motion of a particle is based on certain parameters. And acceleration is one of them. In vertical projectiles the gravitational pull by the earth $mg$ acts on the body.

'Favourite Man' Newton now comes into the scene and states in its second law that

The acceleration of an object as produced by a net force is directly proportional to the magnitude of the net force, in the same direction as the net force, and inversely proportional to the mass of the object (considering mass is constant).

So we get
 $ \vec {a}=\frac {\vec {F}}{m} $

In your car we will have $F=mg$. This will leave us with the value of acceleration as $g$ irrespective of the mass(since masses will get cancelled out). So both lighter and heavier particle will have the same range.

Comment: If they have the same velocity how can the range be the same? That’s what I don’t understand. Would a heavier object not need more initial velocity to even move?

Comment: Here you have considered the initial velocity to be same. Now that is a different case that the heavier particle will require more force for the same velocity. This event is not included in your question.

Comment: Is there a relationship between force and initial velocity in relation to projectiles? If more force is required to project a heavier object due to its mass how can it have the same range and initial velocity as a object with less mass?

Comment: For eg. you are setting up an experiment where you need to throw two particles: heavy and light. You think of throwing both the particles with the same initial velocity. For the heavier particle you have to put a bit more effort to throw it with the same velocity as that of lighter particle. Once both of them acquire the same velocity the range will be same for both which is quite evident from the formula of range. What force you have applied to move that particle doesn't depend at all.

Answer (score 1):

A way to answer is just to write down the equation of motion and let you see that mass is not involved. However, I think that your question may lie on a more deep level. It seems stupid but, perhaps, I can in turn ask you *why not*? Let me explain, and sorry for the length of the answer.

Let's analyze the motion of a projectile on the Earth. We have an initial velocity with some angle with respect to the ground. At each point, the object will feel the gravity and so, instead of keeping going straight along the direction of the velocity, it will fall down. The motion is easy described by splitting the velocities in two components, the horizontal and the vertical. As for the first, the motion is a constant-speed one, while the second one is uniformly accelerated. The combination of the two defines the trajectory which turns out to be a parabola. Notice that in all this description I never said that the mass cannot have some kind of role and, indeed, so far the *light* and the *heavy* object may, in principle, follow two different parabolas and/or fall down at different distances.

But *they do the same path* and the reason are two:

1. The *velocity* is the amount of space done in a certain time unit. To define it you just need the position of an object in two points and divide it by the time spent to move, and nothing else. This means that *all other properties* of your object have no role in what *velocity* describes of the motion of the projectile in your example. Both the *light* and *heavy* object have the same velocity, so at this level *there's no difference between them* at this stage. Formally and logically, this just prove that the horizontal motion, which involves only the concept of velocity, will be the same.
2. The gravity acceleration does not depend on the mass. That's a fact, we observed this during the centuries and this is implemented in our theories. In our example, this means also that both the *heavy* and *light* object behave exactly in the same way from the point of view of gravity. The acceleration term enters in the description of the vertical motion of or projectile. Then, we now found that also the vertical motion will be the same.

If you write down the equation of motion, you will find exactly what said above.

Now I want to reverse the question and try to answer. *Why not?* I think that this kind of doubt is due to an erroneous application of our every-day experience (and this is perfectly normal) in which we are forced to merge our observation with other phenomena related to the *dynamics* and not only to the *kinematics* of the problem. We are driven to say that an heavier object will fall before (or after?) because we think that it is more difficult to move with respect to a light one. But this is *a different phenomenon* and Physics is able to describe this: if we kick a ball, the velocity that it will get would depend on its mass, and this is a true fact. But it is, in the same time, a different story which has nothing to do with our problem above: yes, somebody gives a kick at the projectile, but we do not need details about that because we know the velocity just after... and that is all we need to describe the motion. And also yes, the same kick would have probably produced different trajectories for the two objects. But, as said before, this is an other story. I think that reversing the answer is a way to understand why we do not expect a certain phenomenon to be in some way. Personally, I do this very often in classical physics problems because in several cases the reverse question is posed better than the initial one, allowing to solve the doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, no problem about the lenght. Could you elaborate on “if we kick a ball, the velocity that it will get would depend on its mass”?

Comment: Sure. Here I was referring to a kick as a transfer of impulse: in the most simple case, if you transfer a certain amount of momentum $p$ to an object, it will move with velocity $v=p/m$, so that higher the mass, less the speed. But in you have same velocity, not same transfered momentum.

Comment: Ok, I think I’m getting it. But if I apply an initial velocity at an angle to a snooker ball and the exact same velocity to a larger object with greater mass, shouldn’t the range of the snooker ball be greater and travel further?

Comment: No, they would be the same as I wrote before: in our case (no air resistance, no energy loss and so on) they will fall down exactly in the same point.

Comment: So if a train traveling at a constant velocity crashed into a solid wall causing it to be projected [not to be broken apart and making the assumption of no rotation etc] a distance would the distance be the same if it crashed into a lighter object like a football?

Comment: No, here you are talking about dynamics, don't be confused about this (re-read my answer). If a train kicks something, it will transfer a momentum which will give different velocities to the objects with respect to their mass (exactly what I said two comments above). In Physics we impose that the momentum is conserved, not the velocity.

Comment: So am I getting confused about projectiles and momentum equations? If a train hits a stone wall and the wall is projected a distance, should I use transfer of momentum? Would the initial velocity at the instant the wall leaves the train have the same velocity (projected initial velocity) as a lighter object and therefor the same range?

Comment: No, I repeat: they will have a different velocity given by the formula some comments ago, so in that case **that is not that of the original question** a lighter object would have greater range.